# MS Access - Change Field Value with Button

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a button which, when clicked, I want to change the value of the `Status` field to `Closed`.

How can this be achieved?

I have tried `Me.status = "Closed"` and a few variations of it but suspect that I am not using the syntax.

**UPDATE:**

It is an unbound button (called "Close") within a Single form which has a bound table.

This is what I want to happen:

- User clicks "Close" button;
- The value within the "Status" field on the active record changes to "Closed"

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Explain where is this control placed - Continuous form, sub form? What is the Control type - TextBox, ComboBox? Where is this button? Is the form Bound or UnBound?

Comment: Unbound button, single form, within said form.

Comment: If the form is unbound you cannot do this, you might need to write SQL to UPDATE the table where the data is residing, this is the long way of doing it. The easy way is to bind the table to the form, then what you have `Me.Status` should work.

Comment: I see.  I have split my database into a back end (tables exist here) and front end (forms exist here) - can this still be achieved?

Comment: Absolutely. Your tables are still **linked**, so there is no need to use unbound forms. If you have any questions, give a shout will try and help you out.

Comment: Excellent.  In fact, my form refers to a record source which is located in the back end in order to grab the data, but the button still doesn't do what I'd like it to.  Any ideas what else might be problem?

Comment: Can you post the complete code behind the button along with the record source of the form?

Comment: Button code (closeCase):

=[Status - Open/Closed]="Closed" ['Status - Open/Closed' is the name of the field]

Record source:

CCG COMPLAINTS

I'm afraid that I can't post any more than that as the database deals with highly confidential and sensitive data.

Comment: I suggest you post code and obfuscate the details to maintain security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

This is the VBA code that I wrote which works perfectly for me.  Hopefully others may also be able to use it.

```
Private Sub closeCase_Click()
    Me.[Status] = "Closed"
    Me.refresh
End Sub
```